# How to solve an intro-differential equation with integrals.

Tags: laplace-transform

$y'(t)-y(t)-3\cdot\int[e^{x-t}\cdot y(x),x,0,t]=16\cdot t, y(0)=16$

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to evaluate the integral to solve with the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is to solve
$$y'(t)-y(t)-3\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{e}^{x}y(x)\mathrm{d}x=16t$$
with $y(0)=16$, then you can differentiate wrt $t$ and get
$$y''(t)-y'(t)-3y(t)+3\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{e}^{x}y(x)\mathrm{d}x=16.$$
Now you can use the first equation to replace the integral term and obtain the new ODE
$$y''(t)-4y(t)-16t-16=0.$$
The homogenous solution is given in general by
$$y(t)=A_+\mathrm{e}^{2t}+A_-\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\quad\quad A_+,A_-\in\mathbb{R}.$$
To find a particular solution, you may check it as a polynomial in $t$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your steps more?  How did you get the 3y(t) and how do you just "replace" an entire intergral term?

Comment: @Christina From the first above equation, we have $3\mathrm{e}^{-t}\int\mathrm{e}^{x}y(x)\mathrm{d}x=y'(t)-y(t)-16t$. The term $3y(t)$ comes from differentiation with respect to $t$ of the integral term : as the upper bound of the integral is $t$, differentiating yields $\mathrm{e}^ty(t)$ that you must combine to the factor $3\mathrm{e}^{-t}$, giving you the term $3y(t)$.